# Read URL parameters

Tags: reactjs

I have a very basic app and I want to read the request parameter values

http://localhost:3000/submission?issueId=1410&score=3

Page:

```
const Submission = () => {
    console.log(this.props.location); // error

    return ();
}

export default Submission;
```

App

```
const App = () => (
   <Router>
       <div className='App'>
           <Switch>
               <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
               <Route path="/submission" component={Submission} />
               <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
           </Switch>
       </div>
   </Router>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you setup correctly react-router-dom with the HOC in your Submission component ?

Example :

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const Submission = ({ history, location }) => (
  <button
    type='button'
    onClick={() => { history.push('/new-location') }}
  >
    Click Me!
  </button>
)

export default withRouter(Submission)
```

If you already did that you can access the params like that :

```
const queryString = require('query-string');

const parsed = queryString.parse(props.location.search);
```

You can also use new URLSearchParams if you want something native and it works for your needs

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
const foo = params.get('foo'); // bar
```

Be careful, i noticed that you have a functional component and you try to access the props with `this.props`. It's only for class component.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a functional component you will need the `props` as a parameter of the function declaration. Then the **props** should be used within this function without `this`.

```js
const Submission = (props) => {
  console.log(props.location); 
  return (
    <div />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The location API provides a search property that allows to get the query parameters of a URL. This can be easily done using the `URLSearchParams` object. For example, if the url of your page `http://localhost:3000/submission?issueId=1410&score=3` the code will look like:

```
const searchParams = location.search // location object provided by react-router-dom 
const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams)
const score = params.get('score') // 3
const issueId = params.get('issueId') // 1410
```